# Как установить фиксированную скорость прорисовки и шагов мира в Box2D и SFML?

Tags: c++, разработка-игр, sfml, box2d

Имеется простенький проектик, Box2D занимается физикой, SFML рисует.
На разных машина с разной производительностью скорость работы программы меняется.
Как установить фиксированную скорость? Так что бы на мощном, среднем и слабом компьютере скорость работы программы(движения объектов) были одинаковыми?

Comment: Как устроен основной цикл обновления логики? Есть ли у вас `delta time` - время, затраченное на обработку предыдущего кадра?

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, такого нет.
Box2D ставит генерирует координаты, нужно настраивать его.

Answer (score 0):

Используй sf::Clock

```
world.Step(clock.restart().asSeconds(), velocityIterations, positionIterations);
```

https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Clock.php